# Checking if all even-indexed elements in a (zero-based indexed) list are even

Tags: haskell

I want to write a `fstEven` function that checks if the even-indexed integers in a list are all even; since in Haskell lists are have zero-based indexing, an even index corresponds to an odd position, and therefore an example of correct outputs would be

```hs
> fstEven [2,0,2,0]
True
> fstEven [1,2,3,4]
False
```

My attempt is this:

```hs
fstEven :: [Int] -> Bool
fstEven [] = False
fstEven (x:_:xs)
  | x `mod` 2 == 0 = True
  | otherwise = fstEven xs
```

But it seems to always give true as long as the last even position in the list is even, regardless of the others.

Comment: This question is under discussion on Meta: [What does this question mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402181/4642212).

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that it will return `True` from the moment *one* of the other items is even. So it basically means "*Any other* element is even".

You should check it the other way around: an empty list means every other element is indeed even, whereas from the moment one of the other elements is odd, we return `True`, so:

```
everyOtherEven :: [Int] -> Bool
everyOtherEven [] = True
everyOtherEven [x] = even x
everyOtherEven (x:_:xs)
    | even x = everyOtherEven xs
    | otherwise = False
```

or we can work with:

```
everyOtherEven :: [Int] -> Bool
everyOtherEven [] = True
everyOtherEven [x] = even x
everyOtherEven (x:_:xs) = even x && everyOtherEven xs
```

For example:

```
Prelude> everyOtherEven [2,0,2,0]
True
Prelude> everyOtherEven [1,2,3,4]
False
Prelude> everyOtherEven [2,3,4]
True
Prelude> everyOtherEven [2,3,4,5]
True
Prelude> everyOtherEven [2,3,4,5,5]
False
```

Answer (score 1):

When a function has type `[a] -> b` it makes me think of using a fold. But folding over every other element seems a bit tricky, as folds usually act on every element. Let's take a closer look.

Notice that instead of checking if every other element is even, we could check that for **all** elements either its value is even **or** its index is odd.

```
myEven (idx, v) = odd idx || even v
```

First we [`zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip) the input with a list of indices `[0..]`, then we use [`all :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all) to fold a list of pairs of indices and `Int`s to a `Bool`.

```
everyOtherEven :: [Int] -> Bool
everyOtherEven = all myEven . zip [0..]
  where
    myEven (idx, v) = odd idx || even v
```